# working with nested if query

Tags: php, if-statement, nested

Hi I have a field which is supposed to display 1 of 3 icons based on a 2 conditions.

The key field here is `VisitPlanRequired`, if the answer to this is a "No" then the the icon should be na.png, however if it a "Yes", it then depends on another variable.

So if VisitPlanRequired = yes, then the two options are either ok.jpg or notok.jpg, the actual decider is whether the field `VisitPlanIssued` is null or contains a date, so if it contains a date, it should go to "ok", if it doesnt, it should go to notok.

This is the code I have so far, but I am struggling to get it to work for all three conditions, I would appreciate your help:

```
if ($data["VisitPlanRequired"]==='No')
   $value="<img src=images/na.png id='image'>";

elseif 
($data["AuditPlanIssued"])
{   $value="<img src=images/ok.jpg id='image'>";}

else
   $value="<img src=images/notok.jpg id='image'>";
```

Comment: So, what exactly are the values you're working with, and what does your code do or not do that you expect or not expect?

Comment: well the code partially works, if there is no visit plan required then the NA icon appears, however if there is a yes in that field, it always displays the notok icon, even if there is a data value in the second condition

Comment: So `var_dump($data["AuditPlanIssued"])`, what do you have there?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this (really the basics of programming actually...

```
if ($data["VisitPlanRequired"] == 'No'){
   $value="<img src=images/na.png id='image'>";
}else{
    if( !empty($data["AuditPlanIssued"]) ){
        $value="<img src=images/ok.jpg id='image'>";
    }else{
        $value="<img src=images/notok.jpg id='image'>";
    }
}
```

Success

Comment: The only difference here is the use of `empty`, which you should not be using unless the variable may legitimately not exist. Otherwise the code is identical to OPs.